# How can we calculate the energy resulted from rotary friction welding?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, friction, torque, power

I'm trying to find out the relation between the rotational speed, friction resulting at the contact surface, and raise in temperature between two steel rods (rotary friction welding), so I wanna know how to connect between all these parameters to measure the power of the motor and speed needed to raise the temperature until it starts welding.

Answer (score 2):

Given the geometry, friction coefficient and angular velocity can then be calculated the power dissipation at the interface, relatively easily.

[Consider e.g.](https://youtu.be/-aEuAK8bsQg) the set up in the video (link)

Assume both cylinders to be of radius $R$ and that they are held together by a force $F$. Now we make one of them rotate at angular velocity $\omega$ (while holding the other still)

Now the pressure between both surfaces must be:

$$p=\frac{F}{\pi R^2}$$

Now consider a ring at $r$ and with width $\mathrm{d}r$. The **normal** force $\mathrm{d}F_N$ on that ring is given by:

$$\mathrm{d}F_N=2\pi r\mathrm{d}r \times \frac{F}{\pi R^2}$$
$$=\frac{2F}{R^2}r\mathrm{d}r$$

Constant torque $\tau$ applied to one of the cylinders (as well as a reactive torque to hold the other one still) to keep it rotating at constant $\omega$:

For the infinitesimal ring:

$$\mathrm{d}\tau=\mu_k \mathrm{d}F_Nr=\frac{2F\mu_k}{R^2}r^2\mathrm{d}r$$

where $\mu_k$ is the kinetic friction coefficient.

The power dissipated by friction on the infinitesimal ring becomes:

$$\mathrm{d}P=\omega\frac{2F\mu_k}{R^2}r^2\mathrm{d}r$$

And for the entire disc interface:

$$\int_0^{P_{tot}} \mathrm{d}P=\int_0^R \mathrm{d}r\left(\omega\frac{2F\mu_k}{R^2}r^2\right)$$
$$P_{tot}=\frac23 \omega \mu_kF R$$

---

If we now assume all this energy is converted to thermal energy, without losses (in reality there may be radiative losses, sound and light losses) we can use Fourier's Law of Heat Conduction:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha \nabla^2 T$$

Assuming Steady State (all temperatures have become invariant to time), this reduces to:

$$\nabla^2 T=0\tag{1}$$

To find the temperature at the interface the heat influx would then have to be incorporated. And unless insulated, heat energy losses through convection and radiation would also have to be taken into account. This may require a numerical solution.

Instead let's try a highly simplified solution, so we can at least form an idea of the *shape* of the solution. Consider:

- the cylinders are long compared to their radius ($L\gg R$) We can then consider the problem as *quasi*-1D
- we ignore all losses
- we consider only one cylinder which receives $\frac{P_{tot}}{2}$ heat energy
- we consider the far end ($x=L$) to be at constant temperature $T_0$.

$(1)$ solves simply as:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2T}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow T=c_1 x+c_2$$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are integration constants.

We know that $T(L)=T_0$, so that:

$$T_0=c_1 L+c_2$$

For the second boundary we use Fourier's first law, at $x=0$:

$$\frac{P_{tot}}{2}=-k\left(\nabla T \right)_{x=0}$$
where $k$ is the heat conductivity:

$$\frac{P_{tot}}{2}=-k\left(c_1\right)_{x=0}$$
$$\Rightarrow c_1=-\frac{P_{tot}}{2k}$$
and:
$$c_2=T_0+\frac{P_{tot}}{2k}$$
We can now calculate the temperature at the interface because $T(0)=c_2$, so:

$$T(0)=T_0+\frac{P_{tot}}{2k}$$

This is a very simple model but it can easily be improved on.

---

For example the case where there are convective losses along the length of the cylinder (in accordance with Newton's Law of Cooling) is also fairly easy to solve. The differential equation for that case is (note: also steady state):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2T}{\mathrm{d}x^2}-\frac{Ph}{Ak}(T-T_{\infty})=0$$

where $P=2\pi R$ is the perimeter of the cylinder, $h$ the convection heat transfer coefficient, $A=\pi R^2$ the cylinder's cross section and $T_{\infty}$ the surroundings' temperature.

The same boundary conditions as above can be used.

$$T(L)=T_{\infty}$$

$$\frac{P_{tot}}{2}=-k \left(\nabla T \right)_{x=0}$$

We make a small substitution:

$$\Theta=T-T_{\infty}$$

So that:
$$\Theta(L)=0$$
And:
$$\frac{P_{tot}}{2}=-k \Theta'(0)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2T}{\mathrm{d}x^2}-\frac{2h}{Rk}(T-T_{\infty})=0$$
Or:
$$\Rightarrow \Theta''-m^2\Theta=0\tag{2}$$
With:
$$m^2=\frac{2h}{Rk}$$
$(2)$ solves classically to:
$$\Theta = c_1\sinh mx + c_2\cosh mx$$
Applying boundary conditions:
$$0=c_1\sinh mL + c_2\cosh mL$$
$$\Theta'=c_1m\cosh mx -c_2m\sinh mx$$
$$\Theta'(0)=c_1m-0=-\frac{P_{tot}}{2k}$$
$$c_1=-P_{tot}\sqrt{\frac{R}{8kh}}$$

$$c_2=-c_1\tanh mL$$
$$\Rightarrow T(0)=T_{\infty}+P_{tot}\sqrt{\frac{R}{8kh}}\tanh \sqrt{\frac{2h}{Rk}}L$$

Comment: Wonderful, @gert!!! -NN

Comment: Thanks you, NN!